# How do I add a range of numbers positioned relative to its criteria?

Tags: google-sheets

I'd like to sum up some named values by referring to their names in a separate sheet. Can I do this with a single formula in the second sheet?

Sheet 1:

```
|  A  | 3 |
|  B  | 5 |
|  C  | 2 |
|  D  | 4 |
```

Sheet 2:

```
|  A  |
|  A  |
|  C  |
|  B  | 
| =13 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's possible.

### Formula

Add the following formula in `Sheet2!A5`:

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1:A4;Sheet1!A:B;2*SIGN(ROW(A1:A4));0),"")))
```

### Explained

1. the `VLOOKUP` retrieves the corresponding value
2. the `SIGN` returns an array of the same length to that of the `VLOOKUP`, so that the `ARRAYFORMULA` works
3. the `IFERROR` returns nothing upon error
4. the `ARRAYFORMULA` will take on a range, rather than a cell
5. the `SUM` sums it up !!

### Note

Make sure the ranges are fixed (`A1:A4`) or place the result of the `ARRAYFORMULA` somewhere else.

### Example

I've prepared an example file for you and added a second column in sheet2, so that you can see what happens. Try replacing an `A` with an `E`. Example file: **[SUM VLOOKUP](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdC1HVzh2bGJrUURZYzYtUmJ2SFgyVnc&usp=sharing)**